# redirect page on session timeout in java

Tags: java, session, servlets

I need to redirect the Page to the index page on session timeout. My sessionDestroyed Method is like this;

```
 @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession sess = se.getSession();
        HttpServletRequest request = null;
        String username  = (String) sess.getAttribute("username");
        LogoutDao lgod = new LogoutDao();
        lgod.logoutUser(username);
        request.getrequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    }
```

This is what I have tried and it is not redirecting to index page.

Comment: Well of course it isn't redirecting. As typed, it doesn't even compile, but assuming that's a typo, it is getting a `NullPointerException` when you call `request.getRequestDispatcher()` with a null value of `request.` And when you fix that, which you can't, because you can't get an `HttpServletRequest` from an `HttpSessionEvent,` it still wouldn't do anything, because you aren't doing anything with the result of `getRequestDispatcher()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send a HTTP response as long as the client hasn't send a HTTP request. Simple as that. That's just how HTTP works. The Internet would otherwise have looked very different if any website was able to unaskingly push a HTTP response without the client having requested for it.

A JavaScript based heartbeat based on client's keyboard/mouse activity like as answered here, or a meta refresh header like as answered here would be the solution if you've basically a single-page webapp (thus, you're effectively not using the session scope but the view scope), but that won't work nicely if you've the page open in multiple tabs/windows in the same session.

Websockets is in theory the right solution to push something to the client, but this requires in turn an active session. Chicken-Egg problem. Also, it wouldn't work in older browsers currently still relatively widely in use, so it should currently merely be used for progressive enhancement.

Your best bet is to just define an error page which deals with the case when the enduser invokes an action while the session is expired. See also javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an JavaScript refresh snippet into the response page with the timeout of the session's.

You can also use "Refresh" field HTTP header.

Refer to:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields and search for "Refresh"